# Maximum SD card class for Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: sd-card, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I am thinking of getting a 64 GB micro SDXC card, but I am unsure wether to get a class 10 or UHS-1 for my I9505G with 16 GB.

I've read so many conflicting reports. Some [say](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/267781-class-speed-sd-card-galaxy-s4.html) that the max the device supports for proper function is class 6. Others [say](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/571973-microsd-suggestions.html) that the UHS-1 card works just fine.

What is the maximum class that the device allow to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Use Class 10 SD cards. There will be fewer problems.

Comment: **Note**: class 10 SD card still might give some issues. Consider using lower class if possible. ([related question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134408/should-low-class-sd-cards-be-used-in-android-devices)).